# Is there a way to have carousel page with same header and footer in Xamarin.Forms ?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Trying to have different controls as a items in carousel page. All these control share the same header and footer. Is there a way in xamarin.forms to have common header and footer in carousel page ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CarouselView.

I suggest to try [this](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) because the official one is already in Beta.

To init you have

In your iOS and Android projects call:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Init();
CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
```

then in C#

```
var myCarousel = new CarouselViewControl();
myCarousel.ItemsSource = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
myCarousel.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplateSelector (); //new DataTemplate (typeof(MyView));
myCarousel.Position = 0; //default
myCarousel.InterPageSpacing = 10;
myCarousel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

or, in XAML, first add

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
```

then

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl Orientation="Horizontal" InterPageSpacing="10" Position="{Binding myPosition}" ItemsSource="{Binding myItemsSource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

Comment: Hi, I write everything in c#, what is MyTemplateSelector? I look through all the example, but didn't come out one.